# How is the type of this function inferred?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, type-inference

I'm scratching my head to figure out the signature of this function

```
let make_rec f_norec =
  let rec f x = f_norec f x in
  f
```

which should be

`val make_rec : (('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>`.

Note there is a strange recursive definition. Definitely I'm missing some knowledge out there. Can anyone show me how to compute the type of the function (as the type inference system does)?

Great thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with the inner ones, and working outwards:

1. let us call the type of `x`  `a`
2. then `f` has type `a -> b` where `b` is the result type of `f`
3. `f_norec` takes `f` and `x` and it must return the same type as `f`, hence `(a->b) -> a -> b`
4. `make_rec` takes `f_norec`, and it returns `f`. Hence `((a->b)->a->b)  ->  (a->b)`. For syntactic reasons, the last pair of parentheses can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is quite pedagogical.

Comment: What I do not understand, why the last pair of parentheses can be omitted?

Comment: @Indicator This is how the right associative -> operator works, and it is made this way because if you have a function `f :: a -> b -> c` then this means that if you supply only the a-argument, you get a function `b -> c`. This is currying. OTOH, if the type is `(a -> b) -> c` this means that you have a one argument function that takes another function `a -> b` and returns a `c`.